# How to write PathPrefixStripRegex in Traefik?

Tags: regex, go, strip, traefik, mux

I have a Docker containers that are running on the ECS Cluster on AWS. I am using Traefik to route certain routes to services. For this I am using **DockerLabels** option in CloudFormation and one of them is `traefik.frontend.rule` and `PathPrefixStripRegex`. I had before `PathPrefixStrip` rule as

```
traefik.frontend.rule: "PathPrefixStrip: /api/service-name"
```

and everything was working without a problem. Now I am trying to expand the `api` part to match multiple values like

```
traefik.frontend.rule: "PathPrefixStripRegex: /{basepath:(?:api|docs)}/service-name"
```

The problem is what ever url I call the whole path is stripped. So for example, if I call

```
https://my.example.org/api/service-name/health
```

the Traefik is stripping everything. So `/api/service-name/health` part is removed and the service is being called at the `/` (root) path.

Does anyone have any clue why the whole path is being stripped? Is the regex part wrong, I know the Traefik is using Gorilla mux under the hood and frankly I do not have any experience with Go nor mux.

I have tried to use `/(api|docs)/service-name` as regex. On regex101 site, it works as expected, when I tried to use it as a rule in Traefik, it does not. The version of Traefik is 1.7.

Comment: I am having the same issue! Similar question over at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50885435/traefik-pathprefixstripregex-frontend-rule-doesnt-seem-to-set-the-path-properly